# Running a WPF dialog from a test

Tags: c#, wpf, xunit.net, modern-ui

When I run a ShowDialog call from within a Unit test, I'm getting a

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a task scheduler.

Running from main works fine.  I realize this isn't the normal use of a tester, but it's valuable to be able to pick a dialog and click a button to run it with test data, to see if the dialog works.  However this bug prevents me from running it.

Is there maybe a trick to run the dialog code on the "proper" thread?

Here's the Unit testing code:

```
[Fact]
static public void Draw2()
{
  var uiThread = new Thread(Draw20);
  uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  uiThread.Start();
  // Wait for the UI thread to finish
  uiThread.Join();
}
  static void Draw20()
  {
    ModernUIApp1.MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

    System.Windows.Forms.Integration
      .ElementHost
      .EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
    window.ShowDialog();
    window = null;
  }
```

Window code:
    
>

```
    <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="welcome">
      <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="my page" Source="/Pages/BasicPage.xaml" />
      </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="settings" GroupName="settings">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="software" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

    <mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="settings" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
    </mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

Comment: which codes cause this ? Maybe you can post your code and your unit test details.

Comment: Have you googled "The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a task scheduler"?

Comment: Yes, and I find the discussion is around Task objects.  Not helpful to my understanding.

Comment: On which thread is this exception originating?  Your test thread or the UI thread you are creating?  Also, which unit testing framework are you using?  Which test runner?

Comment: The UI thread gets the exception.  I'm using the Visual Studio embedded test runner with xunit.net.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show WPF UI from a unit test, you'll need to spawn a new thread, ensure it's [single-threaded apartment (STA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165316/stathread-and-multithreading), create the UI from that thread, show the dialog, then marshal the results back to the unit test thread.

```
var uiThread = new Thread(MyCreateAndShowUIFunction);
uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
uiThread.Start();

...

// Wait for the UI thread to finish
uiThread.Join();
```

By and large, unit tests aren't intended to actually launch the UI. That would be an integration test, or even a coded UI test.

Comment: I tried this code, but the same issue arises in the new dialog thread.  Now about your comment, enlighten me: What tool should be used for integration test or coded ui test, and why is that better than a unit tester?

Comment: Show us the code you're using; you should be able to test the UI in a unit test if you spawn an STA thread to create and deal with the UI.

Comment: So when you create your main window and all other UI stuff? You need to put that inside MyCreateAndShowUIFunction like I show above.

Comment: I did Judah, it doesn't help.  Still the SynchronozationContext error.

Answer (score 0):

Searched around for this error, and it looks like you may need to [set your own sync context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245926/the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used-as-a-taskscheduler):

```
[SetUp]
public void TestSetUp()
{
  SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a problem with your unit test runner or some code within the dialog, as I can run your code just fine with ReSharper's xUnit runner.  My dialog contains only a button to set the `DialogResult`, and the test completes without any exceptions.

You could try running this **on your UI thread** before creating the dialog:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
    new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
);
```

If this does not work, try combining it with @JudahHimango's answer of creating a SynchronizationContext for the test thread.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested on the UI thread, no luck.  As for your test, I can also get a button working.  What fails is when I add a Home.xaml page to the example.

Comment: Well, that certainly narrows it down.  Are you calling any code in that page that uses the `System.Threading.Tasks` APIs or `async/await`, perhaps indirectly?  Also, did you try combining my idea with Judah's idea of setting `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());` for the test thread?