# Running Load Tests against Visual Studio Online From TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, load-testing, azure-devops

I created a Load Test that I would like to run every night so that I can compare the results over time.

I'm trying to trigger the load test to run from a TFS build.  Tests are run by Visual Studio Online agents.

Here is the MSTest command that is being executed, however I'm getting an error and the load tests never run.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"F:\Builds\8269\Tests\LoadTests\src\Tests\xxxxx\Remote.testsettings" /searchpathroot:"F:\Builds\8269\Tests\LoadTests\bin" /resultsfileroot:"F:\Builds\8269\Tests\LoadTests\tst" /testcontainer:"F:\Builds\8269\Tests\LoadTests\bin\LoadTest2.loadtest" /publish:"https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection" /noprompt /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/13578" /teamproject:"Tests" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Release" /runtitle:"MySweetLoadTests"
```

Error...
 The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

From here ([The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245926/the-current-synchronizationcontext-may-not-be-used-as-a-taskscheduler))
It says I need to setup a SynchronizationContext, however I'm not sure how to do that within a load test.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a related article, I couldn't get this to work though. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93c8634f-b6d6-4d8a-8c8c-b6eb6c1fad06/tfs-2013-and-webtests-and-load-tests?forum=tfsbuild

Answer (score 0):

This now supported. Please refer to the blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/08/24/cloud-load-test-support-in-mstest-exe-command-line-and-xaml-builds.aspx

Comment: While posting links as a source is a good practice, you should copy relevant information to the answer. StackOverflow is supposed to be "final stop" in search for a solution.