# 'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.' in Console application

Tags: c#

```
 sealed class Program
    {
        static WebsiteAccessor _accessor;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

     WebsiteAccessor.CreateAsync("URL_HERE").ContinueWith(m =>
            {
                _accessor = m.Result;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        }
    }
```

The code above works just fine on WPF (MVVM) and WinForms, but for some reason, it's not on console applications.

The error being returned:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245926/6527049

Comment: I am having the same issue, but with a DLL project

Comment: I've just solved mine by putting `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());` in my function